# Reading a text file Java, Number Format Exception

Tags: java, try-catch, numberformatexception

I'm having some trouble with a method in some code I am trying to write. I basically just want this method to pass an integer that is in a text file into another method(setStrength, setAccuracy, etc.). The source code below and text file is attached. Please help in any way you can. Thank you!

```
public static void loadGame(String loadFileName) { 

    System.out.println();

        try {
            System.out.println("Finding file...");
            FileInputStream loadFileStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/Tyler/eclipse-workspace/myfirsttextgame/src/myfirsttextgame/" + loadFileName + ".txt");
            System.out.println("Loading Game...");
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner("/Users/Tyler/eclipse-workspace/myfirsttextgame/src/myfirsttextgame/" + loadFileName + ".txt");
            while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
                player.setStrength(Integer.parseInt(inputStream.next()));
                System.out.println("Strength Loaded");
                player.setAccuracy(inputStream.nextInt());
                player.setHeight(inputStream.nextInt());
                player.setWeight(inputStream.nextInt());
                player.setStamina(inputStream.nextInt());
            }   
            System.out.println("Character Loaded Successfully.");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception Occurred:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
}
```

Comment: where is txt file attached , could not find it

Comment: How and where did you declare **player**? `Players player = new Players();` Are the **setStrength()**, **setAccuracy()** , etc methods declared as **public** within what I assume is the **Players** Class?

Answer (score 0):

The [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) occurs when an object attempts to parse the String to an Integer wherein the String is not of an appropriate Integer format. The error will be coming from `player.setStrength(Integer.parseInt(inputStream.next()));` where you attempt to convert a String to an Integer. Do some debugging by printing `inputStream.next()` to console and ensure that it is an appropriate Integer format (No whitespace, non-numeric characters, etc).

Also, the FileInputStream object you have created is redundant.

`FileInputStream loadFileStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/Tyler/eclipse-workspace/myfirsttextgame/src/myfirsttextgame/" + loadFileName + ".txt");`

You create a FileInputStream and don't use it again; Instead, before closing it, you create a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)) with the path to a file as the constructor parameter; It will create an InputStream which may conflict with the original unused FileInputStream.